# Clone and resize SeismicCube

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

i'm quite new in Ocean Framework. I have an issue about copy a SeismicCube object with different size. I got to resize K index of the cube for time/depth resampling. All I knew is clone a cube with exactly same properties. Something like this:

```
 Template template = source.Template;
 clone = collection.CreateSeismicCube(source, template);
```

with source is the original cube and clone is the result. Is it possible to find a way to resize clone to different size? size of index K (trace length) particularly. I've explored the overload methods of CreateSeismicCube but still can't understand how to fill the correct parameters. Do you guys have a solution about this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a seismic cube using the overload that clones from another seismic cube you do not have the ability to resize it in any direction (I, J, or K). If you desire a different K dimension for your new cube, then you have to create it providing the long list of arguments that includes the vectors describing its rotation and spacing. You can generate the vectors from the original cube using the samples nearest the origin sample (0,0,0) of the original seismic cube.

Consider that you have the following locations in the cube expressed by their I,J,K indexes. Since the K vector is easy to generate, only needing sample rate, I'll focus on I and J here.

First, get positions at the origin and two neighborhing traces.

```
Point3 I0J0 = inputCube.PositionAtIndex( new IndexDouble3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
Point3 I1J0 = inputCube.PositionAtIndex( new IndexDouble3( 1, 0, 0 ) );
Point3 I0J1 = inputCube.PositionAtIndex( new IndexDouble3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
```

Now build segments in the I and J directions and use them to create the vectors.

```
Vector3 iVector = new Vector3( new Segment3( I0J0, I1J0 ) );
Vector3 jVector = new Vector3( new Segment3( I0J0, I0J1 ) );
```

Now create the K vector from the input cube sampling. Note that you have to negate the value.

```
Vector3 kVector = new Vector3( 0, 0, -inputCube.SampleSpacingIJK.Z );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally someone suggests an answer. The problem solved with another solution which I found easier for me to understand. But your answer give me more options to solve this problem.